# How to use primary - foreign key concept for checking multiple table

Tags: asp.net, sql

Can anyone help me a bit.

i am using this basic script for my goal:

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Check-UserName-Availability-in-ASP.Net-using-JQuery.aspx

now what i want to achieve is , it should check in 3 tables for same username and confirm shows:

In which table it exist and in which it don't.

So how to achieve that goal can anyone just tell me i am thinking to :

Make a table (4th) with a primary key as username and it will contain usernames.

Now in other 3 tables i will make those tables username as foreign key and link the 4th table username with it.

Now my question is : What stored procedure function to call to achieve that goal ?

Comment: Can you post what you have tried?

Comment: Foreign key concept isn't for checking rows existing - it's for ENFORCING rules for tables. In your case, why not to use simple query?

Answer (score 2):

```
select t1.Name as name1, t2.Name as name2, t3.Name as name3 from Table1 t1
full outer join Table2 t2 on t1.Name = t2.Name
full outer join Table3 t3 on t1.Name = t3.Name OR t3.Name = t2.Name
```

Comment: wow that was what i am looking for.. but a simple last question.. how to display result based on that query..

Comment: One of possibilities: http://asp-net-example.blogspot.com/2008/11/aspnet-sqlcommand-example-how-to-use.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try with following queries.

If you want each Table as row:

```
SELECT 'Table1' AS Tbl, COALESCE((SELECT 'Yes' FROM Table1 WHERE Name = 'Joe'),'No') AS Exist
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Table2', COALESCE((SELECT 'Yes' FROM Table2 WHERE Name = 'Joe'),'No') AS Exist
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Table3', COALESCE((SELECT 'Yes' FROM Table3 WHERE Name = 'Joe'),'No') AS Exist
```

Or if you want single row and each Table as column

```
SELECT 
   CASE WHEN t1.Name IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END as Table1
  ,CASE WHEN t2.Name IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END as Table2
  ,CASE WHEN t3.Name IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END as Table3
FROM Table1 t1
FULL JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Name = t2.Name
FULL JOIN Table3 t3 ON t1.Name = t3.Name OR t3.Name = t2.Name
AND t1.Name = 'Joe' AND t2.Name = 'Joe' AND t3.Name = 'Joe'
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6f3ad/7)**

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy exactly what i need.. :)  but using asp how to view that in grid or something ?

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to check this code on button click after user fill a textbox ???

Comment: @JohnKim Use the example from the link you have posted. Just put this code in  stored procedure (`spx_CheckUserAvailability`) instead of the one provided there.

Comment: hmm ok.. i will try and update it in few hours.. i just reached same solution.. Thanks for the reply though bro :D

Comment: so i guess in place of name " Joe" in query i need to run the username correct :)

Comment: @JohnKim Yes, instead of `'Joe'` use input parameter `@UserName` :)

Comment: Hey buddy i am unable to implement this in my code.. :(  i am successful to implement the code in background but i am unable to get output on screen with code.. i don't understand what to update to get it done.. please help.. :(